# Splide.js + React .sync() method does not work on multiple slides with custom thumbnails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, splidejs

I would like to achieve the slider that is similar to one from Amazon's product page. That means if I click the product photo, a modal with the enlarged photo in the slider with thumbnails will come up.
I used splide.js's sync() function and React's useRef hooks to achieve this, according to the [official doc](https://splidejs.com/tutorials/thumbnail-carousel/). However, the same image that has the same index as the main image does not show up on the modal. I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

**Hero.tsx**

```
import { Options } from '@splidejs/splide';

import '@splidejs/react-splide/css';

import './Hero.scss';

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import HeroModal from './HeroModal';

export default function Hero() {
  const MainImages = [
    require('../assets/image-product-1.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-2.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-3.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-4.jpg'),
  ];
  const thumbsImages = [
    require('../assets/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-3-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg'),
  ];

  const mainOptions: Options = {
    type: 'slide',
    perPage: 1,
    perMove: 1,
    gap: 0,
    autoWidth: false,
    pagination: false,
    isNavigation: true,
  };

  const mainRef = useRef<Splide>(null);
  const modalRef = useRef<Splide>(null);

  const [clickedThumb, setClickedThumb] = useState<number>();
  const [modalExpanded, setModalExpanded] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleThumbs = (id: number) => {
    if (mainRef.current) {
      mainRef.current.go(id);
    }
    setClickedThumb(id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mainRef.current && modalRef.current && mainRef.current.splide) {
      modalRef.current.sync(mainRef.current.splide);
    }
  }, [mainRef.current]);

  const handleSlideClick = () => {
    setModalExpanded(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className="hero-container">
        <Splide
          options={mainOptions}
          ref={mainRef}
          onClick={handleSlideClick}
          aria-expanded={modalExpanded}
          aria-controls="hero-modal"
        >
          {MainImages.map((image, index) => (
            <SplideSlide key={index}>
              <img src={image} alt={`product image ${index}`} />
            </SplideSlide>
          ))}
        </Splide>

        <ul className="thumbnails">
          {thumbsImages.map((thumbnail, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <button
                onClick={() => handleThumbs(index)}
                className={
                  clickedThumb === index
                    ? `thumbnails-btn active btn-${index}`
                    : `thumbnails-btn btn-${index}`
                }
              >
                <img src={thumbnail} alt="product thumbnail" />
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
      {modalExpanded && (
        <HeroModal modalRef={modalRef} setModalExpanded={setModalExpanded} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

**HeroModal.tsx**

```
import { Options } from '@splidejs/splide';
import '@splidejs/react-splide/css';

import './HeroModal.scss';

import { useState } from 'react';
import CloseIcon from './CloseIcon';

export default function HeroModal({
  modalRef,
  setModalExpanded,
}: {
  modalRef: React.RefObject<Splide>;
  setModalExpanded: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}) {
  const modalOptions: Options = {
    type: 'loop',
    perPage: 1,
    perMove: 1,
    gap: 0,
    autoWidth: false,
    pagination: false,
  };
  const ModalImages = [
    require('../assets/image-product-1.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-2.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-3.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-4.jpg'),
  ];
  const thumbsImages = [
    require('../assets/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-3-thumbnail.jpg'),
    require('../assets/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg'),
  ];

  const [clickedThumb, setClickedThumb] = useState<number>();

  const handleThumbs = (id: number) => {
    if (modalRef.current) {
      modalRef.current.go(id);
    }
    setClickedThumb(id);
  };
  const handleModalClose = () => {
    setModalExpanded(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="hero-modal" id="hero-modal">
      <div className="hero-modal__inner">
        <button className="close-btn" onClick={handleModalClose}>
          <CloseIcon />
        </button>
        <div className="hero-modal__slide-container">
          <Splide options={modalOptions} ref={modalRef}>
            {ModalImages.map((image, index) => (
              <SplideSlide key={index}>
                <img src={image} alt={`product image ${index}`} />
              </SplideSlide>
            ))}
          </Splide>

          <ul className="thumbnails">
            {thumbsImages.map((thumbnail, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleThumbs(index)}
                  className={
                    clickedThumb === index
                      ? `thumbnails-btn active btn-${index}`
                      : `thumbnails-btn btn-${index}`
                  }
                >
                  <img src={thumbnail} alt="product thumbnail" />
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some React relevant issues:**

In your code I see that:

- You've missed some deps in the deps array inside your `useEffect` function, which won't run the `useEffect` function as expected. Because of that `sync` function is never reached.
- React doesn't recommend you to use the `.current` inside your deps array because: "Mutable values like 'mainSlider.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component."

**Without using Conditional Rendering:**

If you just add the correct deps, and you don't deal with **conditional rendering** it should work fine:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mainRef.current && modalRef.current && mainRef.current.splide) {
      modalRef.current.sync(mainRef.current.splide);
    }
  }, [mainRef, modalRef]);
```

[Here's a full example stated in the docs.](https://github.com/Splidejs/react-splide/blob/master/examples/src/js/components/ThumbnailsExample.tsx)

**Using Conditional Rendering:**

In your scenario: for the sliders that are rendered conditionally I manage to pull it off using the `onMove` function:

```
const moveSliderOnlyOnChange = (slider: Splide, newIndex: number) => {
    if (slider && slider.index !== newIndex) {
      slider.go(newIndex)
    }
  }
  const onModalThumbnailsMove = useCallback(
    (newIndex: number) => {
      const slider = mainRef.current

      if (slider && slider.splide) {
        moveSliderOnlyOnChange(slider.splide, newIndex)
      }
    },
    [mainRef],
  )
  const onModalMainMove = useCallback(
    (newIndex: number) => {
      const slider = thumbnailsRef.current

      if (slider && slider.splide) {
        moveSliderOnlyOnChange(slider.splide, newIndex)
      }
    },
    [thumbnailsRef],
  )
  ...
  <Splide ref={thumbnailsRef} onMove=((_splide, index) => onModalThumbnailsMove(index)) />
  <Splide ref={mainRef} onMove=((_splide, index) => onModalMainMove(index)) />
```